# Control the duty cycle of my square oscillator

Tags: pwm, oscillator, dac, duty-cycle

I Would like to know how i can control the duty cycle of my circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhUcm2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What is the best way to control the duty cycle ( from 1 to 99%) of my circuit?

Comment: How have you set the duty cycle at present?

Comment: If you're not fixed on having this topology, in particular, you can change it to make sure that your feedback has different charging and discharging of the capacitor. Here's a very quick'n'dirty thought on which you could invent yours: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpgtB.png

Comment: If you want to do some circuit analysis one simple way is to assume the inputs in the circuit have ZERO current flowing out of them. You're then looking at the current flowing between the input to the two NAND gates. You're then looking at the time it takes for the capacitor to charge and discharge with R2 acting as the current limiter.

Comment: With what input control mechanism are you favouring? A voltage that sets duty perhaps or maybe just a pot?

Answer (score -2):

Here my answer for the problem.

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to answer your own question or are you asking for feedback on how you attempted to solve the problem? In any case, it's way better if you add some explanation to the figure.